# phpmailerException: The following From address failed, using smtp in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using smtp in drupal to send emails. it was working fine. but suddenly it stopped working and got this error message 
phpmailerException: The following From address failed:  in 
PHPMailer->SmtpSend() (line 731 of ..\modules\smtp\smtp.phpmailer.inc).

Actually, I'm using gmail smtp, also, it Send mail as another email account.

Here is the gmail configuration:
smtp server: smtp.gmail.com
Secured connection using SSL, port 465

An update: here is the error that appear while I'm debuggin the code:
"fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"

Anybody helps?

Comment: What version of PHPMailer are you using? I suggest you read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: Also, you need to post your code, and show your debug output.

Comment: Phpmailer version is 5.1

Comment: Oh dear. That's 6 years old. Update it, as it has little hope of connecting to gmail.

Comment: Also, the failure happens when executing this line in phpmailer
$this->smtp_conn = @fsockopen($host,    // the host of the server
                                 $port,    // the port to use
                                 $errno,   // error number if any
                                 $errstr,  // error message if any
                                 $tval);   // give up after ? secs
All paramaters are correct, howeve $this->smtp_conn value is false after executing

Comment: actually it is the latest version that drupal 7 provides

Comment: So report that as a bug in Drupal, or update Drupal, or import the later PHPMailer version yourself. Unfortunately Drupal has a long history of using very old libraries and not updating them.

Answer (score 0):

After checking many options; this worked for me:

commented this code

```
 // connect to the smtp server
 //   $this->smtp_conn = @fsockopen($host,    // the host of the server
//                              $port,    // the port to use
  //                            $errno,   // error number if any
    //                          $errstr,  // error message if any
      //                        $tval);   // give up after ? secs
// verify we connected properly
```

and use this instead

```
$contextOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array (
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

$this->smtp_conn = stream_socket_client("{$host}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, 20, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

Comment: As the PHPMailer docs say, this makes it 'work', but does so at the expense of making the connection insecure. It also suggests you're running very old code on PHP 5.6; not a great combination.